# Cannot bind element in change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind jQuery element in `onchange` event.

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropdownid', function(e) {
  // your code
});
```

This is what I tried, but the code above is not executing.

```
$(document).on('change', '#$('.type').find('select').data('data-type')', function(e) {
  // your code
});

var values = $('.type').find('select').data('data-type');
```

print id "dropdownid".

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You got more problems in your code, but most answers here address that. However make sure you get the right data from the data attribute.`.data('data-type')` this function gets the values from the attribute `data-data-type` not sure if that is correct. If you want to get the attribute `data-type` use `data('type')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are forming the selector in the wrong way. You can use a variable like the following way:

```
var values = $('.type').find('select').data('data-type');
$(document).on('change', '#'+values, function (e) {
```

**OR:** Only wrap `#` with quotes

```
$(document).on('change', '#' + $('.type').find('select').data('data-type'), function(e) {
```

Comment: problem is html of dropdown is in modal which loads afterwards therefore  $('.type').find('select').data('data-type'); get undefined on page loads and when modal opens this selectors works

Comment: to solve the problem  $(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {

Comment: but to get id is the main issue in modal as i have move the js code from html to js file

Comment: @afeef, without seeing the full code it difficult to answer...may be you can wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function{........`

Answer (score 0):

You keep jquery function is in quotation which doesn't make it work

```
   $(document).on('change',

     '#'+ $('.type').find('select').data('data-type'), 
       function (e) {

      //your code

       });
```